# Need Full Image as background Cover Scroll, Currently cover is look full Zoomed In. i want actual image to be visible with less zoom not full zoom

Tags: css

Need Full Image as background Cover Scroll for mobile device, Currently cover is look full Zoomed In. i want actual image to be visible with less zoom not full zoom.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
 <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
  <p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
<div class="article">
  <div class="article-img">

</div>
  </div>

<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
  <p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container{
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }

.article-img{
  background:url("https://picsum.photos/536/354");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}
}
```

Attaching the Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing background-image to contain

```
.article-img{
   background-size: contain;
}
```

or

```
.article-img{
   background-size: 100% 200px;
}
```